# The constructor Polygon(int[], int[], int) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, polygon

I am trying to figure out why this program is telling me the constructor is undefined for Polygon.

This is the exception that I get:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Polygon(int[], int[], int) is undefined   
at test.main(test.java:9)
```

Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class Polygon extends Applet {
private int[] xpoints = { 0,-10, -7, 7, 10 };
private int[] ypoints = {-10, -2, 10, 10, -2 };

private Polygon poly;

public void init(){
    poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);

}
}
```

Comment: What do you think     `new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);` does

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code. Please read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: Creates a polygon with the the points in the two arrays

Comment: That's not the full code I only copied the beginning to figure out how to make the polygon.

Comment: Rename your class, or explicitly refer to `new java.awt.Polygon`, which is the class you're trying to construct. The issue is that the compiler is looking for the constructor `(int[], int[], int)` in *your* Polygon class rather than the one from the core Java API.

Comment: That is how I originally had it.  I had the code the exact same except the class name was RandomShapes.  I am taking this code directly from a text book thats why I do not understand why it is throwing this error

Comment: I do not no why it did not have it like this in the text book but importing java.awt.Polygon was the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please define a constructor

```
Polygon(int[] xp,int[] yp,int xLength){
     xpoints=xp;
     ypoints=yp;
}
```

Few things are wrong in your code -

1. You are already initializing your member elements but still trying to again set them using constructor.
2. To call init , you will have to create an object and then you are creating another object using init.

Code it like this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class Polygon extends Applet {
    private int[] xpoints;
    private int[] ypoints;

    private Polygon poly;

    Polygon(int[] xp,int[] yp){
        xpoints=xp;
        ypoints=yp; 
    }

    static public void init(int[] xpoints,int[] ypoints){
       poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it says that your Polygon class must have a constructor suitable to

```
new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: I was under the impression the polygon already had a constructor for those parameters?

Comment: well, it seems not to have yet;-)

Comment: @Leo S/he is looking to construct an instance of `java.awt.Polygon`, which indeed does have such a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a constructor like so:

```
public Polygon(int[] a, int[] b, int c){
    //construct a new Polygon object with the parameters
}
```

The way you have it now you only have the default constructor from `Object` which is `Polygon()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your applet class has shadowed the `java.awt.Polygon` class that you wanted to use.

One possible way to resolve would be to change the name of your applet class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class PolygonApplet extends Applet {
    private int[] xpoints = { 0,-10, -7, 7, 10 };
    private int[] ypoints = {-10, -2, 10, 10, -2 };

    private Polygon poly;

    public void init(){
        poly = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, xpoints.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally had the class named RandomShapes.  I didn't mean to post the class as Polygon.  That was my mistake.  However, even with the change in class name, the same exception is getting thrown.

Comment: Perhaps you have some old `.class` files in your output directory?  Maybe if you delete all your `.class` files, and recompile your `.java` files things will work.

Comment: I figured it out... Java.awt.Polygon has to be imported directly.. Thanks for your help!